# Merge several excel files and align by column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, spreadsheet, vba

I have several excel files in a folder and would like to merge them, but align the merged files by column:

The following code aligns me all the files in a folder by their rows:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\mergeFolder")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point
Range("A1:IV" & Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column.
Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Here you can see the output:

[image]

Any suggestions how to align these files per column?

I appreciate your replies!

***Update***

The error I am getting is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably like this:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
  Dim bookList As Workbook
  Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'change folder path of excel files here
  Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\mergeFolder")
  Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
  For Each everyObj In filesObj
  Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

  'change "A2" with cell reference of start point
  Range("A1:IV" & Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
  if Range("A1").Value <> "" and Range("A2").Value <> "" then
    Range("A1").End(xlRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
  else
     if Range("A1").Value = "" then 
       Range("A1").PasteSpecial
     else 
       Range("A2").PasteSpecial
     end if
  end if
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  bookList.Close
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I get an error at `Range("A1").End(xlRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial`. Any suggestion why?

Comment: Thx for your answer! Please have a look at my update!

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I still get the **same** error as before. I also restarted the sheet again to ensure that everything is working properly... Any suggestion.